# How to create custom PersistentEntityResourceAssembler with Spring Data REST

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-rest, spring-hateoas

I'm using Spring Boot 2.1, Spring Data REST, Spring HATEOAS, Hibernate 5.

I'm looking for a way to filter fields in REST calls. I'm going to use https://github.com/bohnman/squiggly-java but I want to integrate it in Spring resource assembler.

I'm looking for a way to customize the `PersistentEntityResourceAssembler` that is automatically available in REST controllers.
This is the code of the class:

```
public class PersistentEntityResourceAssembler implements ResourceAssembler<Object, PersistentEntityResource> {
    @NonNull
    private final PersistentEntities entities;
    @NonNull
    private final Projector projector;
    @NonNull
    private final Associations associations;
    @NonNull
    private final SelfLinkProvider linkProvider;
    @NonNull
    private final EmbeddedWrappers wrappers = new EmbeddedWrappers(false);

    public PersistentEntityResource toResource(Object instance) {
        Assert.notNull(instance, "Entity instance must not be null!");
        return this.wrap(this.projector.projectExcerpt(instance), instance).build();
    }

    public PersistentEntityResource toFullResource(Object instance) {
        Assert.notNull(instance, "Entity instance must not be null!");
        return this.wrap(this.projector.project(instance), instance).build();
    }

    private Builder wrap(Object instance, Object source) {
        PersistentEntity<?, ?> entity = this.entities.getRequiredPersistentEntity(source.getClass());
        return PersistentEntityResource.build(instance, entity).withEmbedded(this.getEmbeddedResources(source)).withLink(this.getSelfLinkFor(source)).withLink(this.linkProvider.createSelfLinkFor(source));
    }

    private Iterable<EmbeddedWrapper> getEmbeddedResources(Object instance) {
        return (new EmbeddedResourcesAssembler(this.entities, this.associations, this.projector)).getEmbeddedResources(instance);
    }

    public Link getSelfLinkFor(Object instance) {
        Link link = this.linkProvider.createSelfLinkFor(instance);
        return new Link(link.expand(new Object[0]).getHref(), "self");
    }

    public PersistentEntityResourceAssembler(@NonNull PersistentEntities entities, @NonNull Projector projector, @NonNull Associations associations, @NonNull SelfLinkProvider linkProvider) {
        if (entities == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("entities is marked @NonNull but is null");
        } else if (projector == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("projector is marked @NonNull but is null");
        } else if (associations == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("associations is marked @NonNull but is null");
        } else if (linkProvider == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("linkProvider is marked @NonNull but is null");
        } else {
            this.entities = entities;
            this.projector = projector;
            this.associations = associations;
            this.linkProvider = linkProvider;
        }
    }
}
```

My guess is that it's injected somewhere into Spring. I want to customize the JSON content dynamically filtering out fields that I don't want.
I tried to create a copya of the class and annotating it with @Component but it's missing Projector.

What's the right way to customize `PersistentEntityResourceAssembler` in Spring Data REST?

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a `PersistentEntityResourceAssemblerArgumentResolver` which creates the 
`PersistentEntityResourceAssembler` on the fly if a controller method needs it.

*It works this way, because `PersistentEntityResourceAssembler` needs the `projection` parameter from the request, so it cannot be a `bean`.*

The argument resolver itself is registered in the `RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration` class.
It's defined in its protected method: `defaultMethodArgumentResolvers()`.
Unfortunately it cannot be configured via `RepositoryRestConfigurer`, so you need to extend the `RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration` configuration class itself then override the `defaultMethodArgumentResolvers()` method.

Unfortunately this method creates a lot of other argumentResolvers too, so I think the best approach is if you call the super method, removes the original `PersistentEntityResourceAssemblerArgumentResolver` from the returning list and adds your custom one into it.

It won't be as easy task... good luck!